# Multiple Scanner class

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I recently appeared for a recruitment test, and the coding problem was fairly simple, so I could easily solve the problem, the only problem which I was facing was getting the input. In the problem the main function was defined and it called another function with just one parameter which was the no. of test cases. I thought it was fair simply as I could simply put a while loop to get my work done. But I couldn't get the input. I faced error stating that no input to the scanner class.
Ideone is giving runtime error? Can anyone tell what is the exact problem?

> http://ideone.com/v6wfao

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int x=sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println(x);
    callit();
    }
    public static void callit()
    {

        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int u=sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println(u);
    }
}
```

Comment: So, 1) `x` is the number of the test case to run 2) the number is typed in via console STDIN? 3) And you are not allowed to modify the `main` method? What is `callit()` supposed to do? I don't see the described parameter of the method. ( "another function with just one parameter" ). It is unclear whats the point of the assignment, was there a description what should be done?

Comment: @burna - the problem was easy and I could solve it. But I couldn't get the inputs. And this is just an easy derivative of the code. I don't remember the exact code but there was something `int x=sc. XYX .trim()` which might help in extracting as @Zizouz212 mentioned the probable problem

Comment: ok sorry, I certainly wouldn't have got the job ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a theory, but I'm not completely sure...

The `Scanner` class uses an `InputStream` where data is redirected there after each line break. This is why, when using a `Scanner`, that you can type 3 numbers on the same line, and nothing will be processed until you click <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Think of it like this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

The Scanner will now take any input from the Standard In, and it will place it into the buffer unique to that scanner.

Therefore, if you type this in:

```
2
3
```

Then both numbers will be in the `sc` object, even though you only called `sc.nextInt()` once.

---

For a solution, I see one:

Make the `Scanner` a static variable. Like so:

```
class IDEOne 
{
    static Scanner sc;

    public static void main(String[] args) // Yada yada...
```

This will keep any input provided from the Standard In to one object, which will also be easier to manage. Therefore, I've created this as a working example derived from your code:

```
class Ideone
{
    static Scanner sc;

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println(x);

        callit();
    }

    public static void callit()
    {
        int u = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println(u);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Zizouz212. I understood the problem. But how to solve it if I cannot access the main function? and the statement used with scanner was `int s=sc. XYZ.trim()` (I don't remember the exact command) how to work then?